# Magento 2: Invalid customer attribute in collection filtering

Tags: magento2, customer, collection, factory

I'm getting a strange error after filtering through `customerFactory`.

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid attribute name: is_active.

```
private function getCustomerDetails()
{
    $collection = $this->_customerFactory->create()->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', array('eq'=>'1'));
    return $collection->getSelect();
}
```

If I replace `is_active` with something else (e.g. `lastname`) then it works just fine. I googled a lot, but could not find a solution to this problem.

Any ideas :?

Comment: I think you need `addFieldToFilter(''is_active',1)` I think this field don't EAV

Answer (score 5):

`is_active` is not an attribute which available to add to select, or filter.
You are still able to have a workaround for this problem by:

```
private function getCustomerDetails()
{
    $collection = $this->_customerFactory->create()->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToSelect('*');
    $collection->getSelect()->where('is_active = ?', 1);
    return $collection->getSelect();
}
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

You get an error because the `is_active` attribute does not exist for customers in Magento2.
There is a column `is_active` on the `customer_entity` table, but if you don't have an attribute with the same code and type `static` you cannot use that attribute for filtering.

To understand better what I'm saying here is an example.
[There is a column](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Setup/InstallSchema.php#L105) called `lastname` in the `customer_entity`   tablebut there is also [an attribute](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Setup/CustomerSetup.php#L193) with type `static` called `lastname`.
That's why filtering by lastname` works.
From my point of view, you just found a bug, or at least an inconsistency and you should report it [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues).